# SAXParseException when trying to print data in table

Tags: java, jasper-reports, xml-validation

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jr:table'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":component}' is expected.

Why it occurs?

Answer (score 0):

you provide almost no context for your question, so your chances of getting a helpful answer are slim.

however, that looks like the sort of exception you would get if you are parsing an xml document with a schema defined and the document does not match the schema.

UPDATE:

based on your comment below, i see the document does list a schema, so my original guess still stands.  your xml document does not match the schema (e.g. there is a "table" element where the schema says there should be a "component" element).

Comment: What kind of context need to be here?

Comment: @user1301035 You should post the jrxml file

Comment: That file is too big, i'll post the declaration of the table.

Comment: <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
     <datasetRun subDataset="TableDataset">
      <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
       <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
      </datasetParameter>
     </datasetRun>